# Python compare two lists of IPs and return the lowest to 0 IP entry in list?

Tags: python, ip-address

I have managed to compile two lists of IP addresses. used and unused ips as such

```
unused_ips = ['172.16.100.0/32', '172.16.100.1/32', '172.16.100.2/32', '172.16.100.3/32', '172.16.100.4/32', '172.16.100.5/32', '172.16.100.6/32', '172.16.100.7/32', '172.16.100.8/32', '172.16.100.9/32'...]

used_ips = ['172.16.100.1/32','172.16.100.33/32']
```

what I want to be able to do now is compare these lists and return the next free IP. in the above example the next ip would be 172.16.100.2/32, until it handed out all of those from 1 to 32 then it would hand out 34.

im not sure where to begin with this, I can convert these to IPv4Network objects if there is something built in for this but I couldn't find anything in documentation

Thanks

Comment: FYI, in Python3 there is [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html).

Comment: Wouldn't unused_ips be more appropriately named 'all_ips' or just 'ips'? It looks like when an IP is used it's in both lists, it's confusing to name it unused_ips if some of the IPs in the list are actually used.

Comment: You seem to have networks in IPv4 with `32` bits in the mask set to 1? That wouldn't leave any space for hosts (all your IPs are designed for subnetworks) Is that correct?

Comment: Based on your list values, you can instantiate new networks as object representations using the `ipaddress` package that Rob mentioned. `n = IPv4Network('172.16.100.0/32')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd keep a `set` of `ipaddress` objects and manipulate them to allocate and de-allocate the addresses, like so:

```
import ipaddress

def massage_ip_lists():
    global unused_ips, used_ips
    unused_ips = set(ipaddress.ip_address(ip.replace('/32', ''))
                     for ip in unused_ips)
    used_ips = set(ipaddress.ip_address(ip.replace('/32', ''))
                   for ip in used_ips)

def allocate_next_ip():
    new_ip = min(unused_ips - used_ips)
    used_ips.add(new_ip)
    return new_ip

unused_ips = [
    '172.16.100.0/32',
    '172.16.100.1/32',
    '172.16.100.2/32',
    '172.16.100.3/32',
    '172.16.100.4/32',
    '172.16.100.5/32',
    '172.16.100.6/32',
    '172.16.100.7/32',
    '172.16.100.8/32',
    '172.16.100.9/32']
used_ips = ['172.16.100.1/32', '172.16.100.33/32']

massage_ip_lists()
print(allocate_next_ip())
print(allocate_next_ip())
```

Note:

- `/32` is a nomenclature for IP networks, not IP hosts.
- `ipaddress` objects are comparable, so functions like `min()` work on them.
- `172.16.100.0` is a perfectly valid IP address, depending upon the netmask. If you don't want to allocate it, either keep it out of `unused_ips`, or make the program aware of the netmask in use.

Answer (score 2):

You want ips that are in unused but not used:

```
available_ips = [ip for ip in unused_ips if ip not in used_ips]
```

You want to sort them to get the one that's closest to zero. Naive sorting will not work as you have strings; 172.16.xxx.xxx is sorted higher than 172.100.xxx.xxx for example. You can convert the IPs into lists of numbers to sort them correctly.

```
import re
available_ips = sorted(available_ips, key=lambda ip: (int(n) for n in re.split(r'[./]', ip)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to iterate through a list of the available ips, you could do something like this:

```
# Filter unavailable ips from the list of all ips
available_ips = set(unused_ips) - set(used_ips)

# Iterate through list of available ips
for ip in available_ips:
    print(ip) # Or whatever you want to do with the next available ip
```

Comment: That's not how remove works. You want a set operation.

set(unused_ips) - set(used_ips)